# Is media-manager plugin support Android API 7.0 using Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, media-manager

--> Is Media Manager Support Android API 5.0

--> Is Anyone have a Sample code for Audio Player using Media Manager Plugin.

Please Tell Me.

Answer (score 0):

if you check Media Manager's [Github](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) it basically answers all your questions, Under the [Status](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager#status) header you can find the versions, it supports.

> Is Media Manager Support Android API 5.0

Since Android 5 is API 21, yes it is supported. As per the Github docs:

> Xamarin.Android | Yes  | API 16+ | ExoPlayer

Also,

> Is Anyone have a Sample code for Audio Player using Media Manager Plugin.

If you want a basic understanding you can check the blog [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/), In any case, Github has a sample usage as well which can be found [here](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/tree/develop/Samples)